# Sending SMS using PHP API with unicode message

Tags: php, string, function, unicode

I trying to send SMS via RoutoMessaging PHP API. I readed all documentation and examples what i was able to find.
They have PHP example script for sending SMS in unicode format:

```
<?php  
// include RoutoSMS class  
include("RoutoTelecomSMS.php");  
// creating object  
$sms = new RoutoTelecomSMS;  
// setting login parameters  
$sms->SetUssms->SetOwnNum("44792838383838");  
$sms->SetType("unicode"); 
// get values entered from FORM  
$sms->SetNumber($number);  
$message="04220432043E04580435002004370435043B0435043D04350020043E0
44704380020044104430020043C04380020043F0430043C043504420020043F043E
043C044304420438043B0435002E002E002E"; 
$sms->SetMessage($message);  
// send SMS and print result  
$smsresult = $sms->Send();  
print $smsresult;  
?>
```

What i not understand is how i can transform text from submited string to this code needed for including in $message.
Can anyone suggest function to convert text for $message please?
I currently work with PHP version 5.3.3.

Comment: If your number is actually (that number minus the extra 38's), then I suggest removing it.

Comment: AFAIK SMS uses a very old encoding known as PDU. If your library does not convert Unicode to PDU internally, you will have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The message you are sending is a Cryllic text. It's probably in Serbian. It reads as "**Твоје зелене очи су ми памет помутиле...**"

Decoding

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$str = "04220432043E04580435002004370435043B0435043D04350020043E044704380020044104430020043C04380020043F0430043C043504420020043F043E043C044304420438043B0435002E002E002E";
foreach(str_split($str, 4) as $char) echo "&#x{$char};";
```

And this is how you would encode the message

```
$string = "Твоје зелене очи су ми памет помутиле...";
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UCS-2', 'utf8');
for($i =0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    echo strtoupper(bin2hex($string[$i]));
```